# How to send json object to the Controller Action method in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to send my userid and password to my login Controller Action method.

```
//Login button click code

$("#btnLogin").click(function () {
    var userCrdential = {
        UserName: $("inputEmail3").val(),
        Password: $("inputPassword3").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Login",
        content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: userCrdential,
        success: function (res) {
          //  alert("data is posted successfully");
            if (res.success == true)
                alert("data is posted successfully");
            else {
               // alert("Something went wrong. Please retry!");
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(xhr.statusMessage);
        }
    }); 
});
```

and in my home Controller I have login Action method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Login")]
    public ActionResult Login(User userCrdential)
    {
        string userIdtest = userCrdential.UserName;
        string userPasswordtest = userCrdential.Password;
        var result=false;

        if (userIdtest != null && userPasswordtest != null)
        {
             result = true;
        }
        else
        {
             result = false;
        }

        return Json(result);
        //return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

but my action method is not invoking...

Comment: In the firebug it is showing post is ok but displaying follwing error"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:49996/BlueBusApp/@Url.Action(%22Login%22,%20%22Home%22)"...... I have this ajax call from the Common.js file which is inside the Content folder and my controller Action method is inside my Home Controller...

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `content` to `contentType` and call `JSON.stringify` on your data:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/Login",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(userCrdential),
    ...
});
```

See [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You should never hard-code URLs in MVC.

Instead use `@Url.Action`.

```
url: ('@Url.Action("Login", "Home")',
```

`userCrdential` needs to be JSON encoded:

```
JSON.stringify(userCrdential)
```

Also, for the same of your sanity, please use the `fail` method.

```
$.ajax("url")
    .done(function() {
    alert("success");
})
    .fail(function() {
    alert("error");
})
```

One last note, `success` is deprecated as of `jQuery 1.8`; you should use `done` instead.

Comment: Because if you change your router settings the hardcoded value will become invalid and you will have to update two places instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Just change it from:

```
var userCrdential = {
    UserName: $("inputEmail3").val(),
    Password: $("inputPassword3").val()
};
```

to:

```
var userCrdential = "UserName=" + $("inputEmail3").val() + "&Password=" + $("inputPassword3").val();
```

all other things is ok in your code, but make sure your controller parameter having the same parameters passing here i.e. UserName and Password.

however you need to check user input before calling ajax.

Comment: Hi i am getting the following error at firebug NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:49996/Home/Login"  I have my ajax call in my Common.js file and my Login Controller Action is inside my HomeController...

Comment: Just change the controller action from public ActionResult Login(User userCrdential) to public JsonResult Login(User userCrdential).